# Is there a way to conditionally change which sqlite table you are updating?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I basically want something like this. Where if the item exists in the first table update it. Other wise update a different table. Or is there another way to do this? Maybe another conditional where I update the first table, if it returns that 0 records were updated then move to the next table.

```
UPDATE
    CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = 3)  
    THEN table ELSE table2 END 
    SET name="hello" WHERE id=3
```

Comment: You cannot do this in a single `UPDATE` statement.  You can do this using dynamic SQL, say by constructing the statement in Python and changing the query string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would approach it with 2 update scripts

```sql
UPDATE table
SET name = 'hello'
WHERE id = 3;

UPDATE table2
SET name = 'hello'
WHERE id = 3
AND 0 = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM table WHERE id = 3);
```